# Chance of exceeding 5 red balls out of 10, when picking from an infinite resevoir with a 30% red 70% blue.

Tags: combinatorics

I have an infinite number of balls.  30% are red and 70% are blue.

If I pick ten balls, I would expect to get 3 red, on average.

I believe that the number of combinations are:

```
red  blue  combinations
0    10    1
1    9     10
2    8     45
3    7     120
4    6     210
5    5     252
6    4     210
7    3     120
8    2     45
9    1     10
0    10    1
```

So if the chances were 50/50, the chance of exceeding 5 red would be

$\frac{(210+120+45+10+1)}{(1+10+45+120+210+252+210+120+45+10+1)}$

How does the 30/70 probability alter these 50/50 results?

Comment: Instead of "infinite number of balls" you better go for "very large number of balls". It is weird to speak of "30% of infinite". Further you are dealing with binomial distribution here. By 30/70 you cannot just do it with "numbers of combinations" because the combinations are not equiprobable. Apply binomial distribution with parameters n=10 and p=30/70.

Comment: In fact you need only 3 red and 7 blue balls taking them from the pool "with replacement".

Comment: @drhab Should that be p=30/100?

Comment: @user Thanks for the terminology.

Comment: @fadedbee Yes, you are right: $p=0.3$, sorry. 30/70 is what is called  the odds.

Comment: Have you understood the solution from the comment?

Comment: @User Yes, thanks.

Comment: @drhab If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "infinite number of balls" you better go for "very large number of balls".

This because it is rather weird to speak of e.g. "30% of infinite".

Further you are dealing with binomial distribution here.

By odds $30/70$ instead of $50/50$ you cannot just do it with "numbers of combinations" because the combinations are not equiprobable.

Apply binomial distribution with parameters $n=10$ and $p=30/100=0.3$.